# Delphi 7 migrating lockbox 2 to lockbox 3 blowfish encryption

Tags: delphi

in LB 2, I have this function

```
blowfish : tlbblowfish

blowfish.ciphermode := cmECB;

someVar := blowfish.encryptstring(someString);
```

LB 3 is completely different.  How do I get the same result from one of the included functions? perhaps with the TCodec class?  I'm pretty sure thats the right thing to use but it now has so many options that were not present in the old class. so I'm unsure which settings to set.

thanks.

UPDATE:  I think I almost have it, but it appears LB3 requires a password when encrypting and LB2 did not.  NO password won't work. So  maybe I  need to know what the old default or empty password was?

Comment: Why are you migrating. Judging from your other question, it sounds like you are making work for yourself and setting yourself up for regressions

Comment: Some areas I will have to spend time on are in the security/password areas.  I don't really **HAVE** to migrate it, but if its not that much trouble I'd rather use the newer component set.  We have XE2 as well and if we decide to convert it, it seems LB3 is more suited for newer Delphi versions.